# Filepicker for Hololens: List available filepickers?

Tags: c#, uwp, filepicker, hololens

So HoloLens is stupid in that it only recognizes one FilePicker at a time (no matter how many may be installed). I don't believe the developers are going to try making multiple filepickers work.

So, I'm trying to figure out my own filepicker in an attempt to be a proxy-select for other filepickers.

In essence, I want to make a filepicker chooser that appears as a typical filepicker (if that makes sense).

Trouble is, it doesn't appear possible to get a list of pickers installed!

Am I experiencing a pipe dream, or is there a way to invoke a picker from a list of pickers?

Answer (score 2):

For the moment this is a pipe dream, but I sure hope they fix this.  Per the [Windows Holographic FAQ](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/holographic/faq):

> Note: HoloLens **will always use the first app you've installed to handle file storage and this can't be changed**. That means if you install Box and then OneDrive, all apps will use the Box file picker app.

Comment: But the question is, is it possible to obtain the list of available filepickers?

Comment: No, currently this is not exposed via an available api, that is why you always are forced to use the first one you installed regardless of how many you have installed.  I would expect this functionality to show up at the OS level and not be available through public api's similar to Windows 10.

Comment: Yeah, that was my point, that HL is supposedly running a build of Windows 10, are there apis to list filepickers on desktop Win10? I think probably not, but that's the point of the question: to ask if it exists and how to do it if it does.